# C++ Crash reports data unknown

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I currently have a game written in C++ using cocos2d-x.
I'm integrating Crashllytics on Android but I'm having troubles with the crash reports.

I'm throwing an exception as a test.
On a device with Android 6 Crashlytics' reports "???" in the crash log.
Reading on another forum someone said (back in March) they would get the same "???" reports with newer version of Android.

Trying on a device with Android 4.4 using the same setup and exception being thrown in the same place on all tests I can get some crashes but they usually trigger randomly on *.so libs (libandroid.so, libglcore.so for example)  or on C files which aren't from my project like vterminate.cc.

I'm running the command to upload symbols before running the app.
An exception thrown in Java is shown fine on the dashboard.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you using our NDK SDK as well?

Comment: I'm not sure. I followed these instructions to install the plugin via Gradle and enable Crashlytics and NDK kit: https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk

Comment: Gotcha, can you share your init of Fabric and which NDK version you're using?

Comment: Initialization in java:
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());

I'm using version r14b.

Comment: Hmm, can you share your app's bundle id? If you don't want to make it public feel free to email support(at)fabric(dot)io

Comment: Sent the bundle id via email.